# Compute a sequence $A_n$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A_n\ln(A_n)}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can we compute a sequence $A_n$ of positive real numbers, such that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A_n\ln(A_n)}=1$?

One way I can think of, is by defining $A_n\ln(A_n)=2^n$, but how do we extract the formula for $A_n$?

Comment: Use the Lambert function and solve for $A_n$.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis Are you sure you can solve for $A_n$ with the Lambert function? I can't see a way to do it.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n\log(2^n)} = \frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac12\right)^n = - \frac{1}{\log 2}\log\left(1-\frac12\right) = 1$$

Comment: @oliveeuler: $A_n\cdot\ln(A_n)=2^n\Rightarrow\exp(A_n\cdot\ln(A_n))=\exp(2^n)\Rightarrow A_n^{A_n}=\exp(2^n)$. The equation $x^x=y$ has the solution $x=\frac{\ln(y)}{W(\ln(y))}$, with $y=\exp(2^n)$, so $A_n=\frac{2^n}{W(2^n)}$.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis Cheers for responding and clarifying :)

Comment: @achillehui: That doesn't quite work out for me, because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$. So are you suggesting that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^nln(2^n)}$?

Comment: @barakmanos You can ask WA to evaluate [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[1%2F%282^n*n*Log[2]%29%2C{n%2C1%2CInf}]) in closed form.

Comment: @achillehui: Nice! You just made me submit another question here (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/890479/131263). Add it as an answer and I will grant you the V. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most ugly piece in the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A_n\log A_n}$
is the $\log(\cdot)$ in the denominator. If one want to construct an ansatz for the
problem, one should look for something that get rid of this $\log(\cdot)$. The simplest choice is $A_n = \alpha^n$ for some $\alpha > 1$.

As a function of $\alpha$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{A_n\log A_n} = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\alpha^n\log(\alpha^n)}
= \frac{1}{\log\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)^n\\
= -\frac{1}{\log\alpha}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)
= 1 - \frac{\log(\alpha-1)}{\log \alpha}
$$
If is then clear if we pick $\alpha = 2$, we will get $\displaystyle\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{A_n\log A_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n\log(2^n)} = 1$.